# Translation Help with Passive Sentence

Tags: translation, passive-voice

I have the following sentence to translate.

```
日本はカリフォルニア州と同じぐらいの大きさで
ほとんどのヨーロッパの国々より大きいということはあまり知られていない
```

I am having trouble translating the second half.

```
Japan is about the same size as the state of California and
as for it being bigger than most European countries, it is not (being) known very well.
```

Can anyone offer any hints about what the author is trying to say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two suggestions. I think both are ok and other variations are possible. It would be interesting to hear people's comments.

> It is not very well known that Japan is about the same size as the state of California and 
>   much bigger than most European countries.
>
> The fact that Japan is about the same size as the state of California and 
>   much bigger than almost every country in Europe is not very known.

The "fact that" aligns the sentence to "ということ”, "almost every" is close to "ほとんど".

I am taking it that both facts are not well known.